# Как работать с полями redux-form, количество которых изменяется?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Я использую `redux-form`. Мне понятно, как обстоят дела с формами, в которых несколько полей. То есть делаем такую форму:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field name={'first'} ... />
    <Field name={'second'} ... />
    <Field name={'third'} ... />
</form>
```

А потом вот так вытаскиваем данные, по-отдельности с каждого поля:

```
let first = formData.first;
...
```

Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать форму, в которой количество полей динамическое, а сами поля одного рода. Ну, например, у меня есть форма, в которой текст перемежается с полями для вставки пропущенных слов. Что-то такое:

```
Маша пошла гулять на речку и взяла [......]. А потом она встретила колобка и [......] его.
```

И сейчас я вставляю эти `<Field/>` в цикле и каждому присваиваю отдельное имя. Из-за этого очень сложно как создавать форму, так и извлекать данные. Приходится высчитывать количество полей и делать что-то такое:

```
for (let i = 0; i < formData.length; i = i + 1) {
    console.log(formData['fieldNumber' + (i + 1)]);
}
```

Так вот обязательно ли мне задавать для каждого такого поля индивидуальное имя? Как мне избежать такого нагромождения кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует три варианта решения этой задачи.

#### 1. Использование `getFormValues()`

Выглядит это вот так:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    formValues: getFormValues('myReduxForm')(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(MyReduxForm);
```

В параметрах `getFormValues` мы указываем название интересующей нас формы. Это же название мы указывали для формы, когда подключали её к redux-form. Мы получаем `formValues`, это объект, который содержит данные формы:

```
{
    firstField: 'first',
    secondField: 'second',
    thirdField: 'third'
}
```

Дальше не составит никакого труда получить содержимое в виде массива: `Object.values(formData)`.

#### 2. Использование специального имени для `<Field/>`

Итак, если мы создаём `<Field/>` в цикле, то, как правило, мы не можем создавать для каждого поля уникальное имя. Единственное что у нас есть уникальное, это индекс. В таком случае нам следует создавать `<Field/>` следующим способом:

```
<Field name={'keyword.' + index}/>
```

Обратите внимание, что сначала должно идти общее для всех полей слово, потом **обязательно** точка, а потом уже индекс *(вероятно, можно ставить вместо индекса другие уникальные значения, например буквы, я не проверял, но скорее всего так тоже будет работать)*, то есть имя каждого поля должно иметь такой вид: `[ключевое слово].[индекс]`.

Чтобы получить данные полей формы в `onSubmit()`, мы делаем следующее:

```
const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    const fieldsData = formData.keyword;

    // ...
}
```

То есть мы вытаскиваем из объекта `formData` массив с данными формы. Этот массив мы вытаскиваем по тому же имени, какое указывали для всех полей перед точкой: `[ключевое слово].[индекс]`.

Например. Мы создаём в цикле три поля `<Field/>`. Мы указываем имя для них следующим образом: `<Field name={'myField.' + index}/>`. Теперь, когда мы захотим получить данные формы, мы поступаем следующим образом:

```
const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    const fieldsData = formData.myField;
    // ...
}
```

В массиве `fieldsData` будет находится содержимое всех трёх полей.

#### UPD. от 08.07.21

**Будьте крайней осторожны со вторым вариантом!**

Лично у меня с ним возникла проблема. Например у нас есть следующие поля: `keyword.1`, `keyword.2`, `keyword.3`, и мы указали для каждого из них значения. Если стереть значение из первого поля, то в нём тут же появится значение из второго поля, а само второе поле станет пустым! Если опять стереть значение из первого поля, то теперь в нём окажется значение третьего поля, а третье поле станет пустым.

На первый взгляд причина связана с дублированием `key`, но это не так. Проблема заключается именно в имени поля. Если заменить `keyword.1` на `keyword1` или `keyword-1` *(и остальные поля тоже, соответственно)*, то данная проблема исчезает.

Я не скажу, что второй вариант абсолютно плох, потому что я нашёл его на англоязычном stackoverflow и там ни о каких проблемах речи не было *(ссылку я к сожалению потерял)*.

Так как лично я решил отказаться от второго варианта, то у меня снова встала проблема: как получить значение нескольких полей из redux-form, учитывая, что их количество динамическое и может меняться? Я нашёл третий вариант решения этой проблемы.

#### 3. Парсинг `formData`

*Рекомендую данный способ, если вы столкнулись с теми же проблемами во втором способе, что и я.*

Объект `formData` на самом деле представляет из себя самый обычный объект, в котором нет ничего, кроме пар вида `названия поля: значения поля`. Таким образом его легко можно разобрать на части.

Важно понимать, что нельзя получить значения просто через `Object.values(formData)`, если вам важен порядок полей и их значений, потому что `formData` содержит значения не в том порядке, в каком шли поля, а произвольно. Это очень легко решается. Во-первых сделайте так, чтобы названия полей шли в алфавитном порядке *(например, я просто прибавлял индекс к строке `keyword`)*.

Дальше всё просто:

```
const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    const orderedFieldKeys = Object.keys(formData).sort();
    for (let i = 0; i < orderedFieldKeys.length; i++) {
        let fieldName = orderedFieldKeys[i];
        answer = answer + formData[fieldName];
    }
}
```

Собственно, дальше делайте с переменной `answer`, что вам угодно. Это содержимое поля. Таким образом вы по порядку сможете получить значения каждого поля.